# Intent Filters priority causing problems when adding to android manifest for deep linking

Tags: java, android, android-intent, deep-linking

I am trying to add deep linking to my android app. The website domain is suppose cherishx.com

There are 2 paths I want to deep link and both open different activities

- Path 1 - cherishx.com/experiences/some-cateogry
- Path 2 - cherishx.com/experience/some-experience

Please note the main difference above, Path 1 has "experience**s**" and Path 2 is only "experience" (without the s)

The intent filters I have written are as follows:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:host="cherishx.com" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/experiences/.*" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:host="cherishx.com" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/experience/.*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

The funny thing is only the intent filter with "experiences" (s included) gets triggered each time. Unless I comment that intent filter, after which "experience" works fine.

Can't get it to work. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you try it by removing 1)  .* 2) /.*

Comment: Yeah I did try all those permutations, nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

For supplying `<data/>` attributes beyond just `android:scheme`, `android:scheme"` must be supplied also. You **can** continue to use multiple `<data/>` attributes, but if you use anything other than `android:scheme`, you should include `android:scheme` too. For example, you could do this:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="http"
          android:host="cherishx.com"
          android:pathPattern="/experience/.*" />
        <data android:scheme="https"
          android:host="cherishx.com"
          android:pathPattern="/experiences/.*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Or you can do this:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

But not this:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:host="cherishx.com"
          android:pathPattern="/experience/.*" />
        <data android:host="cherishx.com"
          android:pathPattern="/experiences/.*" />
</intent-filter>
```

The reason is that android ignores any attributes in the `<data/>` tag if there is no `android:scheme` attribute. Also, if there is no `android:host`, the port and path attributes are ignored.

According to the docs [[1]](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html):

> DESCRIPTION:
>   Adds a data specification to an intent filter. The specification can be just a data type (the mimeType attribute), just a URI, or both a data type and a URI. A URI is specified by separate attributes for each of its parts:
>   `<scheme>://<host>:<port>[<path>|<pathPrefix>|<pathPattern>]`
>
> These attributes that specify the URL format are optional, but also mutually dependent:
>
> *If a scheme is not specified for the intent filter, all the other URI attributes are ignored.*
>   If a host is not specified for the filter, the port attribute and all the path attributes are ignored.